# SQL to only return child rows if all are the same type

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

So let's start with the database setup:

"Client" table contains clients. Only relevant field is:

```
Client.CLIENT
```

"Policy" table contains policies with 3 relevant fields:

```
Policy.CLIENT
Policy.POLICY
Policy.CLASS
```

I need to return a list of policies where the Client has more than 1 policy and all of their policies are the same Class of policies.

For example, let's say there are 3 classes of policies (A, B, and C).

- If a client has 3 policies and ALL of them are class "A", then return those policy rows.
- If a client has only 1 policy, don't return the row.
- If a client has 3 policies, but two are Class "A" and 1 is class "B", don't return any rows.

Hopefully that makes sense, if not I can expand my question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please prepare sample data using http://sqlfiddle.com and desired result

Comment: The data you explained may seem simple to you,but its hard for others to understand,best way is to prepare some sample data,expected result,any query you have tried

Comment: @lad2025 unfortunately, sqlfiddle hasn't been working for the last couple of months. Does it work for you?

Comment: @Lamak Hmmm, an hour ago I wrote query and it executed successfully.

Comment: @lad2025 for SQL Server?

Comment: @Lamak PostgreSQL, SQLFiddle :( You could always use http://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler

Comment: I just tried doing it with SQLFiddle in SQL Server 2008 mode and it won't build the schema? It's about as basic as it can get so I know it's not a syntax error. I see there's now an answer so I'm going to check that before wasting more time beating my head against SQLFiddle. Thanks!

Comment: @lad2025 didn't know about it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done the way Gordon Linoff suggested, it should be efficient. But if you're not a fan of windowed functions, this should do job just fine and will work in other SQL dialects too:

```
DECLARE @Client TABLE
(
  CLIENT_ID INT
  , CLIENT_NAME VARCHAR(10)
);

DECLARE @Policy TABLE
(
  CLIENT_ID INT
  , POLICY VARCHAR(10)
  , CLASS VARCHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO @Client (CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_NAME)
VALUES (1, 'CLIENT 1')
  , (2, 'CLIENT 2')
  , (3, 'CLIENT 3');

INSERT INTO @Policy (CLIENT_ID, POLICY, CLASS)
VALUES (1, 'POLICY 1', 'A')
  , (1, 'POLICY 2', 'A')
  , (1, 'POLICY 3', 'A')
  , (2, 'POLICY 4', 'A')
  , (2, 'POLICY 5', 'A')
  , (2, 'POLICY 6', 'B')
  , (3, 'POLICY 7', 'A');

SELECT C.CLIENT_ID, C.CLIENT_NAME, P2.POLICY, P2.CLASS
FROM @Client AS C
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT CLIENT_ID
  FROM @Policy
  GROUP BY CLIENT_ID
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CLASS) = 1
    AND COUNT(CLASS) > 1
    ) AS P
  ON P.CLIENT_ID = C.CLIENT_ID
INNER JOIN @Policy AS P2
  ON P2.CLIENT_ID = P.CLIENT_ID;
```

That's the outcome:

```
CLIENT_ID CLIENT_NAME POLICY   CLASS 
--------- ----------- -------- ----- 
1         CLIENT 1    POLICY 1 A     
1         CLIENT 1    POLICY 2 A     
1         CLIENT 1    POLICY 3 A
```

- Client 1 has three `A` policies, that's why it's brought back
- Client 2 has two `A` and one `B` policy so it's not brought back
- Client 3 has just one `A` policy - it's not brought back

Query on data.stackexchange.com: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/511200

Could be useful to toy around

Comment: Only tweak I made was switching from Count(CLASS) to just Count(*) to make it a little less confusing to someone who has to deal with this query in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
select Policy.CLIENT 
from policy 
group by Policy.CLIENT 
having count(*) > 1 and count(distinct(Policy.class)) = 1


select Policy.CLIENT, policy.policy
from policy 
group by Policy.CLIENT, policy.policy 
having count(*) > 1 and count(distinct(Policy.class)) = 1
```

Comment: That answer doesn't take Class into account at all

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. I'll check and see if this will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the list of *policies*, then one option is window functions:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             count(*) over (partition by p.client) as cnt,
             min(p.class) over (partition by p.client) as minc,
             max(p.class) over (partition by p.client) as maxc
      from policies p
     ) p
where cnt > 1 and minc <> maxc;
```